# How to add 2 user input values using OOP in C++ and print with showDetails()

Tags: c++, oop, integer, iostream, cin

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Arithmetic{
    private:
        int x;
        int y;
    
    public:
        Arithmetic(int num1, int num2){
            x = num1;
            y = num2;
        }
        
        Arithmetic(){
        }
        
        ~Arithmetic(){
        }
        
        int getNum1(){
            return x;
        }
        
        int getNum2(){
            return y;
        }
        
        int add(){
            return getNum1() + getNum2();
        }
        
        void showDetails(){
            cout << add();
        }
};

int main(){
    
    Arithmetic a;
    
    int num1, num2;
    
    cout << "Enter Num1: ";
            cin >> num1;
    cout << "Enter Num2: ";
            cin >> num2;        
    a.showDetails();
    
    return 0;
}
```

I've been tasked to add 2 user input values using object-oriented programming in C++. I've been trying to use `cin` inside the main and outside the main but for some reason it won't work. Plus I've been told to not use setters and only getters. And for some reason, I still don't understand how to print `showDetails()`.

P.S. I have no experience in C++ only in Java.

Comment: Use `Arithmetic a(num1, num2);`

Comment: Tip: [`operator+`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). The `add` function here is somewhat pointless. There's no need to call those functions when you already have access to that data.

Comment: Surely in Java, you know how to build an object with data? You took the data in to `num1` and `num2`, and then did nothing with them with respect to `Arithmetic`. What you should to is take the input, and then feed the input to your constructor. Your order of operations is wrong.

Comment: *P.S. I have no experience in C++ only in Java* -- Well, at least you didn't make the mistake that many from Java make, which is this:.-- `Arithmetic* a = new Arithmetic(num1, num2);`.

Answer (score 0):

First, a mini-code review:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;  // Bad practice

class Arithmetic{
    private:
        int x;  // Prefer default member initialization
        int y;
    
    public:
        Arithmetic(int num1, int num2){
            // Prefer using the initialization section
            x = num1;
            y = num2;
        }
        
        Arithmetic(){
          // Should be defaulted and paired with default member initialization
        }
        
        ~Arithmetic(){  // Unnecessary; Rule of Zero
        }
        
        int getNum1(){  // Should be const
            return x;
        }
        
        int getNum2(){  // Should be const
            return y;
        }
        
        int add(){
            // No need to invoke getters, and should be const
            return getNum1() + getNum2();
        }
        
        void showDetails(){
            cout << add();
        }
};

int main(){
    
    Arithmetic a;
    
    int num1, num2;
    
    cout << "Enter Num1: ";
            cin >> num1;  // Poor formatting
    cout << "Enter Num2: ";
            cin >> num2;

    // This is where your issue occurs. You never put the data into the object.
    // Declare 'a' here, and use your parameterized constructor.         
    a.showDetails();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Your issue is order of operations for the most part.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Arithmetic {
 private:
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;

 public:
  Arithmetic(int num1, int num2) : x(num1), y(num2) {}

  Arithmetic() = default;

  int getNum1() const { return x; }

  int getNum2() const { return y; }

  int add() const { return x + y; }

  void showDetails() const { std::cout << add(); }
};

int main() {
  int num1;
  int num2;

  std::cout << "Enter Num1: ";
  cin >> num1;
  std::cout << "Enter Num2: ";
  cin >> num2;

  Arithmetic a(num1, num2);
  a.showDetails();

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
❯ ./a.out 
Enter Num1: 5
Enter Num2: 7
12
```

I left the getters in, but for the question as asked, they could be deleted.